# Sharing node.js / common.js modules

Tags: node.js, bdd, commonjs

I have been writing some modules in a BDD driven way and I chose this type of pattern. The problem is that a method in my Deck Setup module needs to instantiate and call methods from exports.Deck. How would i do this?

```
exports.Deck_Setup = function() {
    var ShuffledDeck=[];

    var card_dummy= [
        {
            Rank:"Queen",
            Suit: "Hearts"
        },
        {
            Rank:"King",
            Suit: "Hearts"
        },
        {
            Rank:"Ace",
            Suit: "Spades"
        }
    ];

    var constructor = function() {};
        constructor.prototype.generateDECK = function(Card, DeckBuilder){
            var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
            console.log(Card, DeckBuilder);
            test = new Card();
            // var new1 = Card.add(card_dummy[0]);          
            // card = new Card(card_dummy[randomNumber]);

        };
            // return (Cards.indexOf(Card) > -1) ? true : false;

    return new constructor();

};
```

---

```
exports.Deck = function() {
    var Cards=[];

    var constructor = function() {};
        constructor.prototype.add = function(Card){
            if (this.size() >= 52){
                return false; //can't add anymore cards
            }
            else {
                Cards.push(Card);
                return true;
            }
        };

        constructor.prototype.remove = function (){
            if (this.size() > 0){
                Cards.pop();
                return true             
            }
            return false;
        };

        constructor.prototype.size = function() {
            return Cards.length;
        };

        //magic method for our cards
        constructor.prototype.includes = function(Card) {
            for (var each in Cards){
                if (JSON.stringify(Cards[each]) === JSON.stringify(Card) ){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
            // return (Cards.indexOf(Card) > -1) ? true : false;

    return new constructor();

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Deck_Setup needs to access exposed methods from Deck, use `require` :

```
var deck = require('./Deck')
```

where the`deck` variable will be the result of your `new constructor`

You can also achieve it by setting both the setup and the Deck factory into the same module (you can export an object:

```
 var Deck = {}
 var Deck_Setup = {}
 module.exports = {
    Deck : Deck,
    Deck_Setup : Deck_Setup
 };
```

May be you should read this blog post and find your own way: http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/export-this/